# Radio Button causing strange behaviour

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist, modalpopupextender

I've got a `ModalPopupExtender` containing a `RadioButtonList` which has 2 `ListItem` buttons.

When the popup is visible, one button is already correctly selected.

If I click the other button, I get `Page_Load` followed by `OnSelectedIndexChanged` events as expected.

My Page_Load handler calls `ModalPopupExtenderExchangeDevice.Show()` which causes the popup to still be visible when the code-behind completes.

The opposite button is now selected, as expected. If I now click the un-selected button, again `Page_Load` followed by `OnSelectedIndexChanged` events fire, but this time the `ModalPopupExtender` is NOT visible.

Any ideas why it isn't?

UPDATE:

Fixed the problem with one RadioButton not working - ASP.NET "helpfully" changes the `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` between buttons, and I had missed it. Sorted.

Having fixed that, the popup is still not showing.

Thanks

Comment: can you please post your code for Page_load and radiobutton selectedindexchage event here

Comment: @radders no code is blocking ModalPopupExtenderExchangeDevice.Show()?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after hours of debugging I found the cause.

Code-behind was adding a `button` to the parent panel which holds the `ModalPopupExtender`. Removing this addition made it start working.

Who knew?